# Tikz standalone the background is transparent make it white

Tags: tikz-pic

I'm using the below Latex code to draw a `tikzpicture`

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png},tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{{xcolor}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw node[draw, fill={{rgb:black,1;white,5}}, minimum size=4cm,line width=0.1cm,font=\fontsize{100}{100}\selectfont, label={[yshift=-6cm,style={font=\fontsize{100}{100} } ] {$x_9$} } ] at (25, 20) {1};
    \draw [line width=0.1cm](25,22.0) -- (25,24.0);
    \draw [line width=0.12cm] (25,25.0) circle (1);
    \draw [line width=0.12cm](25,24.0) -- (25,26.0);
    \draw [line width=0.12cm](24,25.0) -- (26,25.0);
    \draw [arrows={-Triangle[angle=90:0.5cm,black,fill=black,line width=0.1cm]}](26,25.0) -- (25.9999,25.0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The file is compiled with `pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex` and produces the below png.

[image]

Although it can't be seen here, the png has a transparent background ( you can see it with only viewing the image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Idfe.png)). I want it to have a white background directly instead of converting with an additional external tool.

How can we have a white background or any color at once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `backgrounds` library. Notice that this solution assumes that you do not use the `background` layer for other purposes, if you do, you may have to introduce other layers and order them appropriately.

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png},tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,backgrounds}
\tikzset{white background/.style={show background rectangle,tight background,
background rectangle/.style={fill=white}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[white background]

    \draw node[draw, fill={{rgb:black,1;white,5}}, minimum size=4cm,line width=0.1cm,font=\fontsize{100}{100}\selectfont, label={[yshift=-6cm,style={font=\fontsize{100}{100} } ] {$x_9$} } ] at (25, 20) {1};
    \draw [line width=0.1cm](25,22.0) -- (25,24.0);
    \draw [line width=0.12cm] (25,25.0) circle (1);
    \draw [line width=0.12cm](25,24.0) -- (25,26.0);
    \draw [line width=0.12cm](24,25.0) -- (26,25.0);
    \draw [arrows={-Triangle[angle=90:0.5cm,black,fill=black,line width=0.1cm]}](26,25.0) -- (25.9999,25.0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, the white background only includes the tikzpicture, not the standalone border.

Comment: Thanks, now the libary for [LFSR drawing better](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/89829/18298)

Answer (score 3):

If you are making standalone images and don't just want your tikzpicture to have a background, it may be simpler to use `\pagecolor`.

For example, the following code:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png},tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{{xcolor}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{cyan}     % This line here
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw node[draw, fill={{rgb:black,1;white,5}}, minimum size=4cm,line width=0.1cm,font=\fontsize{100}{100}\selectfont, label={[yshift=-6cm,style={font=\fontsize{100}{100} } ] {$x_9$} } ] at (25, 20) {1};
    \draw [line width=0.1cm](25,22.0) -- (25,24.0);
    \draw [line width=0.12cm] (25,25.0) circle (1);
    \draw [line width=0.12cm](25,24.0) -- (25,26.0);
    \draw [line width=0.12cm](24,25.0) -- (26,25.0);
    \draw [arrows={-Triangle[angle=90:0.5cm,black,fill=black,line width=0.1cm]}](26,25.0) -- (25.9999,25.0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces this image with `pdflatex --shell-escape main.tex`:

[image: A black and grey LFSR drawing on a solid cyan background]

However, note that `\pagecolor` appears to mess up the automatic sizing from standalone or something, and your image may be slightly larger than intended and have small transparent edges.