# Tikz scale text together with math text

Tags: tikz-pic

In the below-simplified Latex code, I'm using `scale` to change the font size of the math mode.

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png},tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,backgrounds}
\tikzset{white background/.style={show background rectangle,tight background,background rectangle/.style={fill=white } } }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[white background]
    \draw node[draw, fill={{rgb:black,0;white,5}}, minimum size=4cm,line width=0.1cm, label={ [yshift=-6cm] { $\scaleto{1 2 3x_{ 18 } }{ 20pt }$ } } ] at (25, 20) { $\scaleto{ 0 }{ 30pt }$ };
    \path (current bounding box.north east) +(15mm,15mm) (current bounding box.south west) +(-15mm,-15mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When only math elements exist (inside of the box), there is no problem. As we can see, however, if there are text and math to display the scale doesn't work;

- Math mode removes the spaces, as usual
- Math mode doesn't have `\text` in Tikz as Latex.

What is the correct way to scale both of them?

Comment: Now the LFSR automatic drawing and animations are [finished](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/89829/18298). Thanks to the previous answerer, too [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595870/62865) and [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/596147/62865)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why, just include the `amsmath` package, and use `\text{...}` wherever you like---

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png},tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,backgrounds}
\tikzset{white background/.style={show background rectangle,tight background,background rectangle/.style={fill=white } } }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[white background]
    \draw node[draw, fill={{rgb:black,0;white,5}}, minimum size=4cm,line width=0.1cm, label={ [yshift=-6cm] { $\scaleto{1 2 3x_{ 18 } \text{x} }{ 30pt }$ } } ] at (25, 20) { $\scaleto{ a, 0, \text{a} }{ 30pt }$ };
    \path (current bounding box.north east) +(15mm,15mm) (current bounding box.south west) +(-15mm,-15mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to get both text and math scaled to the sizes mentioned...

[image: scaled-text-math]

#### Edit

To show how it looks with space between *texticized* numerals... `\text{1 2 3}x_18 \text{x}`

[image: scale-text-maths]

Comment: Great!. I prefer this  `$\scaleto{\text{1 2 3 }x_{ 18 } }...` in the answer since I've intentionally written `1 2 3` with spaces.

Comment: That's one way-- no doubt !  Another way is to include forced spaces with `\,`, `\:` or `\;` (or, if you need even thicker spaces, `\quad` or `\qquad`) even in the math-mode... thanks to the `amsmath` package developers :)

Comment: Now the LFSR automatic drawing and animations are [finished](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/89829/18298). Thanks to you and the previous answerers, too. [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595870/62865) and [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/596147/62865)