# How can I make a standalone image with a transparent background?

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, transparency

When I try to make a PNG image using TikZ by using the `convert` option for the `standalone` class, I cannot figure out how to make the background transparent.
I seem to recall some years ago that this happened by default; while I could be misremembering, other questions and answers on here seem to back up that memory (e.g. [`tikzpicture` has clear background by default](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/382726/140224), [this recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595870/140224) stating that the TikZ standalone picture background was clear and asking how to make it white...).
In any case, the default behavior on my machine currently seems to be a white background.
Using a minimal example,

```latex
\documentclass[convert={density=300},tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [ultra thick] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get a circle with a white background:

[image]

How can I make the background transparent?

It may be that software version details matter; I have the following setup:

- OS: Ubuntu 21.10
- LaTeX distribution: TeX Live 2020
- (can provide other details on request, not sure what else to add)

Comment: I do not know `GraphicsMagick 1.4`. On my system I have: `convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-2 Q16 x86_64 2021-06-25 https://imagemagick.org`. First step is to make it work in a terminal - see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618059/8650

Comment: Thanks @hpekristiansen . The more I think about it, I suspect this is some kind of difference between `GraphicsMagick` and `ImageMagick`. Installing `GraphicsMagick` was not a deliberate choice but was chosen to satisfy a dependency by some other program I suppose. I will try to investigate this difference, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `command=` suboption to `convert=` to further specify the `convert` command. Something like this should work:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,command=\unexpanded{{\convertexe\space -density \density\space \infile\space -transparent \space white \outfile}}},tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [ultra thick] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is adapted from the example in the [`standalone` documentation](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf) you linked to.

Be sure to run with `--shell-escape`.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! At some point I will try to investigate why `GraphicsMagick` is different to `ImageMagick` in this respect, but for now, this gives me the result I need